# TS: Escaping reserved keyword and use as variable name

Tags: typescript

Hope this isn't a duplicate, been searching around and not even really found an answer to whether this is possible or not, not to mention how, if that is the case that you can.

My problem is that I'm getting incoming json to my front with variable name `"is-saved"`, how can I use it in my corresponding Typescript class, or can I? So I'm looking for a similar solution I'm doing in my backend (Java):

```
@JsonProperty("is-saved")
private Boolean isSaved;
```

And yes, I'm gonna get an answer from you that just change the name, but I can't, I don't have access to that actual code.

I've found some suggestions and I have tried the following, and do not work:

```
is-saved: Boolean //obviously!
"is-saved": Boolean
'is-saved': Boolean
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've tested it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20isSaved%3A%20Boolean%3B%0D%0A%09public%20'is-saved'%3A%20Boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20test()%3B%0D%0Aa.isSaved%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0Aa%5B'is-saved'%5D%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a.isSaved)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a%5B'is-saved'%5D)%3B%0D%0A), and 'is-saved' seems to work, but there is no intellisense help present.

Comment: @AJT_82: what do you mean that it doesn't work? Also, you probably meant to use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.

@JakubJankowski: In TypeScript 2.0, you'll actually get completions at the end of `foo["`,

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser good to know. But it seems that the playground I have linked to, uses earlier version, so it did not have the autocompletion feature for these "dictionary-like" properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted string members are allowed in TypeScript. e.g. the following class works fine:

```
class Foo {
    'is-saved': boolean;
}
```

Can also be used in interfaces:

```
interface ServerData {
    'is-saved': boolean;
}
```

Comment: How to use this in constructor?

Comment: `this['is-saved']` 